# React programmatically recall a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, polling

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usefetch-cniul

Please see above url for a very simplified version of my code.

I want to be able to refetch data from an API with my hook, within an interval (basically poll an endpoint for data).

What I want is to be able to just call something like `refetch` (as I've shown in the code as a comment), which would essentially just call `fetchData` again and update state with the response accordingly.

What's the best way to go about this? The only way I can think of is to add a `checker` variable in the hook which would be some sort of uuid (`Math.random()` maybe), return `setChecker` as what is `refetch` and just add `checker` to the array as 2nd useEffect argument to control rerendering. So whenever you call `refetch` it calls `setChecker` which updates the random number (`checker`) and then the function runs again.

Obviously this sounds "hacky", there must be a nicer way of doing it - any ideas?

Comment: Also, you can use [fetch-suspense](https://github.com/CharlesStover/fetch-suspense)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a constant poll going, I think you can move the `setInterval()` into the hook like so:

```
function useFetch() {
  const [data, setDataState] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoadingState] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    function fetchData() {
      setLoadingState(true);
      fetch(url)
        .then(j => j.json())
        .then(data => {
          setDataState(data);
          setLoadingState(false);
        });
    }

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      fetchData();
    }, 5000);

    fetchData();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return [
    {
      data,
      loading
    }
  ];
}
```

Remember to include the `return () => clearInterval(interval);` so the hook is cleaned up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const url = "https://api.etilbudsavis.dk/v2/dealerfront?country_id=DK";

function useFetch() {
  const [data, setDataState] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoadingState] = useState(true);
  const refetch = useCallback(() => {
    function fetchData() {
      console.log("fetch");
      setLoadingState(true);
      fetch(url)
        .then(j => j.json())
        .then(data => {
          setDataState(data);
          setLoadingState(false);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return [
    {
      data,
      loading
    },
    refetch
    // fetchData <- somehow return ability to call fetchData function...
  ];
}

function App() {
  const [
    { data, loading },
    refetch
    // refetch
  ] = useFetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // Use the refetch here...
      refetch();
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [refetch]);

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch</button>
      <code style={{ display: "block" }}>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(data[0], null, 2)}</pre>
      </code>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will work, it needs some adjustments to useFetch but you can still call it normally in other places.

```
//maybe you can pass url as well so you can use
//  it with other components and urls
function useFetch(refresh) {
  //code removed
  useEffect(() => {
    //code removed
  }, [refresh]);
  //code removed
}

const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState({});
const [{ data, loading }] = useFetch(refresh);
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(
    () => setRefresh({}), //forces re render
    5000
  );
  return () => clearInterval(interval); //clean up
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to question:

```
export default function App() {
  const [entities, setEntities] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoadingState] = useState(true);

  const getEntities = () => {
    setLoadingState(true);

    //Changet the URL with your own
    fetch("http://google.com", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setEntities(resp);
        setLoadingState(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getEntities();
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
}
```